# Flask and TelegramBot don't start in different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, bots, telegram

I have the following code (app - Flask app, bot - telegram bot):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        Thread(target=app.run(port=Api.port,debug=True,use_reloader=False), args=[]).start()
        bot.infinity_polling()
   except Exception as exception:
        logging.error(exception)
```

But it doesn't run in parallel. First Flask starts and it's waiting for I stop that thread only after that the bot starts. Why it doesn't run in different threads?

Comment: You need to add the code for starting the bot to your question

Comment: sorry, typo. fixed

Comment: Could be because that's the Flask App (i.e. you're trying to run a flask App and so once it starts, it returns the 'app' object which means it can't execute any code after it. What happens if you switch the procedure i.e. start the bot first and then start the Flask App?